# Pre populate Sql data using recursion on each combination

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fill db pre populated data from sql script where I have two type of constants or enums.

**Platform: DG, NK**

**Department : KK, TG, LO, NP, UI, BG, ED, CC.**

Task: To generate a sequential number using procedural loop and for each combination using above value we need to generate key and put in data base with count or sequence value.

Database columns:

```
id(auto generated), count, category_key, status
```

Now single row would be one combination which is formed using this pattern,
**Department_Platform_SequenceNumber :: example => KK_DG_1,....KK_DG_10000, KK_NK_1,....KK_NK_10000**

This is for 10k entries for 10k sequence of each combinations. It follows for other as well.

**Approach:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE
number AS ( SELECT 1 number 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < 10000 ),
platform AS ( SELECT 'DG' platform
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'NK' ),
department AS ( SELECT 'KK' department
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'TG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'LO'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'NP'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'UI'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'BG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'ED'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'CC' )               
INSERT INTO counter_key 
SELECT null, number, CONCAT_WS('_', department, platform, number), 1
FROM department
CROSS JOIN platform
CROSS JOIN number;
```

**Problem:** Getting syntactical error::

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO counter_key  SELECT null, number,
> CONCAT_WS('_', department, platfor' at line 23

Please help me resolve this since I have been struggling to resolve this.

[image: Updated desired result]

Comment: What is `CTE` in first block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in query

1. `cte` does not exist in first Recursive Block.
2. Place the `Insert INTO` statement before recursive block

So your final query should be like below

```sql
insert into counter_key

WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT 1 number 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < 2 ),
platform AS ( SELECT 'DG' platform
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'NK' ),
department AS ( SELECT 'KK' department
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'TG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'LO'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'NP'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'UI'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'BG'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'ED'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'CC' )

SELECT null, number, CONCAT_WS('_', platform, department), 1
FROM department
CROSS JOIN platform
CROSS JOIN cte 
order by 3,2;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfb6f73bc45a197cc7cd4175bd24c8a8)

Comment: In this I wont be getting combination as platform_department right ? because I dont want that

Comment: Error Code: 3636. Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Comment: So its working when I have put 1000 but not in case of 10000....also now is possible to get sequencing as category_key `dept_plat` and count as sequence but now I want all sequence as first in db then after that next category sequence

Comment: I have added image in my question can I get the above sequence with your corrected query?

Comment: if you know pessimistic locking here is something where you could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712809/updating-and-fetching-using-pessimistic-lock